Missing libgl1 and libglib2.0-0 in Nuitka bundled bin
I am trying to bundle my .py script that uses pytorch, OpenCV (generally AI oriented script) to be one-file, standalone file for my custom app deployment purpose. Due to technical limitations I need to use Azure Functions without containers, so I need a Linux binary working on Debian 11.
The problem is, when I use nuitka --onefile --standalone myscript.py (on Debian 11 as well), when I upload the generated .bin into Azure Function, it says "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" both for libgl1 and libgthread-2.0.
I checked that using apt-get install via SSH on that system to get those libraries helps. But I have no option to automate it at the moment.
Is there any option to make "true" standalone binary file using Nuitka, with libgl1 and libgthread-2.0 included?

I think this question is better to be asked in azure or maybe some devops thread. But anyways, you are having problems because those 2 libraries are not in azure's funciton machine. This is probably because that vm is a more lightweight than yours. Usually, what you need to do, is to add the dependencies into the one file. This is a typical problem when compiling .py projects (since python is an interpreted language should not need to be compiled, and it's somehow a bad practice). But anyways, you need to check a way to add dependencies in your compilation.
